# How can i wait the bloc execution in testWidgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

I have the following scenario:
screen button tap -> bloc event -> do a request -> bloc state -> navigate

i want to test that if i tap the button i can navigate..

```dart
Future<void> pumpScreen(WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider<Navigation>(create: (context) => navigation),
          Provider<Bloc>(create: (context) => bloc),
        ],
        child: const MaterialApp(
          home: Screen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
}
```

```dart
testWidgets('', (tester) async {
  mockRepositorySucess();

  await pumpScreen(tester);
  await tester.tap(find.text('button'));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();


  verifyRepositoryCall()
  verifyNavigation()
  },
);
```

The test is reaching the verification and the calls were not done yet. How can i wait for the bloc execution in testWidgets?

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
No matching calls (actually, no calls at all).
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)

Answer (score 0):

when I do Bloc testing and there is a async method will be called I'll first prepare the answer in the setup method

```
  late MocGetFoodCategoriesList mockGetFoodCategoriesList;
  late FoodCategoriesDetailes foodCategoriesDetailes;
  late String categoryName;

setUp(() { 
    mockGetFoodCategoriesList = MocGetFoodCategoriesList();

    foodCategoriesDetailes = FoodCategoriesDetailes(meals: [
      MealDetails(meal: "a", mealThumb: "test", mealId: "1"),
      MealDetails(meal: "b", mealThumb: "test", mealId: "2"),
    ]);
    categoryName = "Beef";
  sut = HomeBloc(getFoodCategoriesList: mockGetFoodCategoriesList,);

    }
```

and then when the bloc asks for it it will be like this

```
 blocTest<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
      'on GetSelectedItemDetailes FoodType.FOOD expect states LoadingHomeState & ListBavaragesHomeState',
      build: () {
        when(
          () => mockGetFoodCategoriesDetailes.call(params: categoryName),
        ).thenAnswer((invocation) async => right(foodCategoriesDetailes));

        sut.selectedFoodType = FoodType.FOOD;
        sut.selectedCategory = categoryName;
        return sut;
      },
      act: (block) => block.add(GetSelectedItemDetailesEvent(categoryName: categoryName)),
      expect: () => [isA<LoadingHomeState>(), isA<FoodDetailesHomeState>()],
    );
```

in this case the Bloc will fire event called `GetSelectedItemDetailesEvent` and  the states that will be fired after the success of calling of `mockGetFoodCategoriesDetailes` that might be your API call or anything else with Async/await function, and checking as in this case that 2 states loading and state that has the result are called and the operation was successful.
here I'm not checking if the results are matching or not.